# malloc seg fault

Tags: c, malloc, qsort

I wrote a function to allocate memory for 2 double variables. It works when the required memory size is small, but causes seg fault when the required memory grows relatively big. Is there any error or bad practise in the written codes?

```
void RDF_MALLOC(void** p, size_t sz){

*p = malloc(sz);
    if (*p == NULL){
        RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Insufficient memory.\n");
    } else {
        memset(*p, 0x00, sz);
    }
}

void RDF_FREE(void* p){
    if (p != NULL){
        free(p);
        p = NULL;
    } else {
        RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Fail to free memory.\n");
    }
}

void calcErr(){

    int PTCORE_MAX_SESSION_NODE = 1800;

    double* sum_least_square_err = NULL;
    double* node_sum_least_square_err = NULL;

    RDF_MALLOC((void**)&sum_least_square_err, PTCORE_MAX_SESSION_NODE*PTCORE_MAX_SESSION_NODE);
    RDF_MALLOC((void**)&node_sum_least_square_err, PTCORE_MAX_SESSION_NODE);

    /* run qsort to sort content in sum_least_square_err , and node_sum_least_square_err...*/

    RDF_FREE(sum_least_square_err);
    RDF_FREE(node_sum_least_square_err);
}
```

---

I get two types of runtime error, either malloc failed, or invalid pointer when free()....

error 1:

```
`malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.`
```

error 2:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./pt: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0b302ba8 ***
```

Comment: Where does `p` point in `RDF_MALLOC()`?  It's not declared.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake, i have edited it to reflect actual code

Comment: Horrible code.  Return the new pointer from `RDF_MALLOC()` rather than using `void **`; it will be **much** cleaner.  The `p = NULL` in `RDF_FREE()` does nothing.  Other than that, I cannot see any issue with your malloc/free code.

Comment: Your `qsort` code must be wrong somehow: you are overrunning a buffer and corrupting the `malloc` information.

Comment: I'd guess that you're not allocating enough memory and that you want to add a `* sizeof(double)` to the size argument of your `RDF_MALLOC()` calls.  But that's just a guess, since you don't show anything about how you use the allocated memory, except for a comment about sorting it.

Comment: `free(p); p = NULL;` The p = NULL statement does nothing, since it only sets the temporary pointer p to point at NULL. The original pointer in main will still point at the heap, where the memory used to be stored.

Comment: @trojanfoe Pointer-to-pointer syntax is pretty widely used and accepted for code like this. So your opinion is completely subjective.

Comment: @Lundin I said the code would be cleaner, nothing more. I also made the point about about `p = NULL` doing nothing, so your comment is completely duplicated.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes but you didn't explain why.

Comment: @Lundin And your explanation doesn't help either; the pointer in `RDF_FREE()` isn't temporary is it?  What does "used to be stored" mean?  If you're going to explain, then explain, and get off your high horse.

Comment: @trojanfoe All function parameters are temporary as they have local scope. The function successfully frees the memory pointed at from the heap - there is no valid memory there any longer. Yet the pointer in main still points at that memory cell.

Comment: could you provide us with the qsort call and the compare callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are not passing the actual size required and overflowing the double array. It would be clear when you paste the qsort code, but most likely in your comparison function you would be comparing two doubles and a double takes 8 bytes where as malloc allocates as many *bytes* passed as an argument.

```
RDF_MALLOC((void**)&sum_least_square_err, PTCORE_MAX_SESSION_NODE*PTCORE_MAX_SESSION_NODE * sizeof(double));
RDF_MALLOC((void**)&node_sum_least_square_err, PTCORE_MAX_SESSION_NODE*sizeof(double));
```